# Please let know if flight from Sydney to Kuala Lumpur No. MH140 arrives on KLIA 1 or KLIA 2

Tags: airport-terminals, kul, malaysia-airlines

Please let us know if the flight from Sydney to Kuala Lumpur No. MH140  arrives on  KLIA 1 or KLIA 2
We need to know this because on our electronic tickets it is not written, it is mentioned as Terminal M.

Answer (score 3):

A [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=mh140+arrival+terminal&oq=mh140+arrival+terminal&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.9120j0j7&client=tablet-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) on Google for 'MH140 arrival terminal' indicates that the flight will arrive at KLIA Main (or KLIA1) at about 04:39 local time.

Answer (score 1):

This flight arrives at terminal 1 (KLIA 1):

[image]

([Source](https://www.flightstats.com/v2/flight-tracker/MH/140))